# How to integrate Cmder properly in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmder

I would like to integrate [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) shell into my VS Code configuration.

I'm using VS Code 64bit on Windows, and I tried to modify my `settings.json` file as follows, to make Cmder work as the integrated terminal:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Cmder\\Cmder.exe",
```

I restarted my VS Code and tried to open the terminal.

At first, this error message box showed up:

> Failed to copy ConEmu.xml file to backup location!
>   Restart Cmder as administrator.

So, I launched VS Code as administrator, which made the error message disappear; however, I noticed that VS Code opens Cmder in another *separate* window instead of in the terminal.

**How can I run Cmder shell inside VS Code terminal?**

P.S. Could this note in vs code documentation be the solution?

> **Tip:** The integrated terminal shell is running with the permissions of VS Code. If you need to run a shell command with elevated (administrator) or different permissions, you can use platform utilities such as `runas.exe` within a terminal."

from: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 11):

There is a mistake in your configuration file, the following is *not* valid:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Cmder\\Cmder.exe"
```

You should **not** be calling **Cmder.exe** from the VS Code, instead, you should use `init.bat` (from the instructions below) to integrate Cmder in VS Code.

Your issue has been already explained [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1930) over the Cmder repository.

#### Making Cmder work in VS Code

1. Make sure you're on the **latest** release of Cmder – download latest [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/releases)
2. Open the `settings.json` configuration file, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (Control-Comma) to access the preferences, then click on the **Edit in settings.json** link
3. VS Code documentation explains the process in this link:
   **[Can I use Cmder's shell with the terminal on Windows?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows)**

   > Yes, to use the Cmder shell in VS Code, you need to add the following settings to your `settings.json` file:
   >
   > ```
   > "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
   > "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "C:\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"]
   > ```
4. BTW, You need to replace `C:\\cmder` with your own installation path.
   **Tip:** replace single backslashes (`\`) with double backslashes (`\\`).
5. Make sure you read the notice at the official Cmder [wiki](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1930#issuecomment-441853031):

   > Please note the use of `cmd.exe` instead of `cmder.exe`.

   **Tip:** refer to [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration#spaces-in-path) on notes about handling *spaces* in your path.
   <sup>TL;DR: It's not recommended by the Cmder team, but you may use `^` character before spaces to handle the paths.</sup>
6. You don't need to restart VS Code to make this work.
   Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (Control-Tilde) to open Cmder in VS Code terminal!

You may refer to my answer [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1930#issuecomment-441853031) for a complete explanation of how this works.

#### Related

There are similar issues [over the VS Code repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12006) and [here on Cmder repo](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1984#issuecomment-446479536) as well.

Comment: cmd.exe is not cmder. if you run cmd.exe you won't have the conemu environment that cmder provides. therefore it may work with cmder's extended cmd but it won't work with git-bash properly, because it won't understand the ansi color codes what it does when runs in cmder.

Comment: Great detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

Cmder [1.3.12](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/releases/tag/v1.3.12) introduced a `vscode_init.cmd` script which allows VS Code tasks to work correctly with Cmder.

The documentation in VS Code, referred to in the answer above, is out of date if you're using a version of Cmder greater than `1.3.11`.

The Cmder GitHub repository now has [extensive documentation](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/wiki/Seamless-VS-Code-Integration) on how to achieve integration between Cmder and VS Code. At the time of writing this message, it is more accurate than [the VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on June 22nd 2021; add these lines to the settings.json file in your user settings (for me « C:\Users\ianla\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json »):

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "cmder": {
      "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
      "args": ["/K", "C:\\Users\\ianla\\cmder\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "cmder",
```

... of course, you'll need to change my « C:\Users\ianla\ » with your instalation "cmder" instalation path.

[See here for more info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_can-i-use-cmders-shell-with-the-terminal-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

The following is that worked for me (version of Cmder greater than 1.3.11):

1. Paste \cmder directory into C:\tools
2. Paste in  .vscode\settings.json :

   ```
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe",
   "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
       "CMDER_ROOT": "C:\\tools\\cmder"
   },
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
       "/k",
       "%CMDER_ROOT%\\vendor\\bin\\vscode_init.cmd"
   ],
   ```

.. and enjoy!

Comment: On vscode April 2021 updates commands `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` and `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"` were deprecated.

Comment: what's the new commands ? i'm looking for those.

Comment: @PajriAprilio Follow the new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67489288/13499978